# What is the svn equivalent to winkin in clearcase?

Tags: perl, svn, clearcase, cleartool

I am new to svn, however I am at present making the transition of some Perl scripts from ClearCase. I know that Clearcase have dynamic views, so it can access one or more derived objects (DOs) from a dynamic view, or convert a nonshareable derived object to a shareable (promoted) derived object by the cleartool command `winkin`. How do I replace it with an equivalent svn command, knowing that svn is static.

Comment: Don't use SVN if you can use git. It will save you a lot of work later. SVN is painfull.

Comment: @simbabque: git can be pretty painful too ;-) For both it depends what you're using them for :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't: Those notion of derived object are very specific to ClearCase dynamic view. [`cleartool winkin`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_winkin.htm) accesses the data of any existing DO, and a DO does not exist in Subversion.

That is similar to "[Is there a git equivalent to `cleartool catcr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31177989/6309)": gcc (meaning the tool using the sources to compile) might have some information, but the source control tool itself (Subversion) won't have any.

```
flag
```

> 1) I had to get rid of the `omake` concept of calling the makefile (I got a `makefile.bat` for the same)

This has nothing to do with SVN or git.
A third-party tool ([OmpenMake](http://www.openmakesoftware.com/), [graddle](https://gradle.org/) or [Bazel](http://bazel.io/) (see "[e](https://gradle.org/gradle-team-perspective-on-bazel/)") would be needed here.

> 2) The cleartool commands like `winkin`, `endview` should be changed so that this becomes svn compatible.

There is no notion of [dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378) in any other tool but ClearCase.

> 3) this changes will stir up changes in the *.LOG file that gets generated on successfully running the *.BAT, I need to have a list of files (URL and revision no. which will be stored in the *.LOG file, for this I need to change the `cleartool describe` command)

That depends on the language and build mechanism you will chose, and not on SVN.
With a modern language like [go (golang)](https://golang.org/), you wouldn't be concerned anymore by the list of files built: only the one with changes would be recompiled.

Comment: This was really helpful. But I have certain roadblocks on this derived objects. I have to convert the builds from clearcase to svn(and i can not use git) So how do i replace the derived object concept with svn equivalent?

Comment: What are your roadblocks?

Comment: 1) I had to get rid of the omake concept of calling the makefile(i got a makefile.bat for the same)      2) The cleartool commands like winkin, endview should be changed so that this becomes svn compatible.     3) this changes will stir up changes in the *.LOG file that gets generated on successfully running the *.BAT, I need to have a list of files(URL and revision no. which will be stored in the *.LOG file, for this i need to change the cleartool describe command)

Comment: That gave a much better understanding to me now. Thank you

Comment: Can we use nmake for the same? I have created a maketarget.bat file. Will nmake work with this? do i need to change the *.BAT file?

Comment: `nmake` (http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UsingNmake) should work there (but it still won't use any of the ClearCase features like winkins)

Comment: print "(nmake -s -k -r -f $MakeTarget)\n" if $debug; if this is the command will it change to print "(nmake -s -k -r -f $MakeTarget)\n" if $debug;

Comment: @RimiGhosh I am not sure that I spot the difference between the two commands.

Comment: The first command being  
print "(omake -s -k -r -f $MakeTarget)\n" apologies for the confusion.

Comment: @RimiGhosh OK: I don't know if all the options from omake are supported by nmake though. I suppose you will need to make some test to check that.

Comment: If i have a command, $res = `cleartool winkin -out $Default;    How can i fetch this in svn? can anyone tell me the process or alternative?

Comment: @RimiGhosh considering my answer started with "cleartool winkin accesses the data of any existing DO, and a DO does not exist in Subversion."... I don't think you can "fetch" that from SVN.